# Multiple Listen Directives

Tags: apache, xampp

I am trying to configure Apache to serve on multiple ports, but when I add multiple listen directives I get a 204.

Works fine with only one listen directive (only the virtual host with the corresponding port)

Here is my vhost config:

```
# Listen
Listen 8013
Listen 8015
Listen 8019

# NameVirtualHost
NameVirtualHost *:8013
NameVirtualHost *:8015
NameVirtualHost *:8019

# Projects
<VirtualHost *:8013>
   ServerName local.dev

    DocumentRoot "/Users/laskew/DEV"
    <Directory "/Users/laskew/DEV">

      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# Subversion
<VirtualHost *:8015>
  ServerName local.svn

  DocumentRoot "/Users/laskew/SVN"

  <Directory "/Users/laskew/SVN">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


# Git
<VirtualHost *:8019>
  ServerName local.git

  DocumentRoot "/Users/laskew/GITHUB"

  <Directory "/Users/laskew/GITHUB">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that in your "httpd.conf" you have it set to listen on port 80. I think that it always needs to be listening on that port.

Also you need to add the directive "AcceptMutex flock" at the end of your httpd.conf file.

Comment: No, Apache can be configured to listen on any port, you are not restricted to port 80. Port 80 is the default port for webbrowsers to look for your server though, that's all.

Comment: The "AcceptMutex flock" directive fixed the issue.